# Fix Div to top when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've used the following code to fix a div to the top of the page when scrolling.

```
$('.container').data("top", $('.container').offset().top);

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('.container').data("top")) { 
        $('.container').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}); 
    }
    else {
        $('.container').css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
});
```

The Element and the parent css is as following.

**Parent**

```
.content-right {
    width: 688px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

**Element**

```
.container {
    background: #FFF;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 687px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

But when I scroll the page, the element doesn't get fixed to the top of the page.
How can I fix this issue?

**Update**

The container is the common style. There are several elements with the same style and I've used a class to identify the wanted element. I've changed the code to this.

**Fiddle** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u2Ce/)

Comment: I don't understand - is your element that you want to stick to the top called .container, or is it .payment-info-container?  Your code seems to refer to both, but I'm not sure which is correct.

Comment: Can you make an online demo like on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Please make a fiddle: jsfiddle.net

Comment: Or at least include your HTML as well

Comment: That code works fine as per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6LAyB/ The problem must lie elsewhere in your code - can you post a fiddle example of it NOT working, or post your complete code for the page?

Comment: You need to add `jquery` in your `file`, and your code is working see [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7u2Ce/1/embedded/result/). You can `inspect` the `containers position` in `console`.

Comment: Yeah in your Fiddle you forgot to set the initial top position for the container and you forgot to include the jQuery library.  Once you do that it works, so there's still something else missing that you need to include for us.

Comment: I found out the issue is! The thing is The value in the $(window).scrollTop() is changing when the user scrolls! And when it hit the condition and if the condition is true, the element position is changed. The parent element height is not fixed and changes according to the child elements. When the specific element position is changed, the height of the parent element is changed thus the position of the $(window).scrollTop(). this makes the condition to be false and makes the element position static. any idea of overcoming this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
var $container = $('.payment-info-container'),
    top = $container.offset().top + $container.outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > top) { 
        $container.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'}); 
    } else {
        $container.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto'});
    }
});
```

See the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/chennanfei/yW5Ne/2/). BTW, you didn't load jquery resource in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try **this**.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamb/F4BmP/)

```js
/* Dynamic top menu positioning
 *
 */

var num = 50; //number of pixels before modifying styles

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
        $('.menu').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.menu').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});

//USE SCROLL WHEEL FOR THIS FIDDLE DEMO
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this one.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="
        background-color: #e8e3e3;
        font-size: xxx-large;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
      ">
    Header
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```